# How to use getInputStream() RunTime object

Tags: java, runtime.exec

please help me to compile and run java files by using the following code snipet.

```
RunTime rt=RunTime.getRunTime();
Process p=rt.exec("//what to write here for compilation of java file");
```

then how will i catch the response by getInputStream().

please brief me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually, starting with Java 6, it's preferable to use the [`ToolProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) api and use the Compiler programatically:

```
JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticListener<? super JavaFileObject> listener =
    new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager javaFileManager =
    javac.getStandardFileManager(listener, Locale.getDefault(), charSet);
javaFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, sourcePaths));
javaFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, classPath);
javaFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, outputPaths);
CompilationTask task = javac.getTask(
    null, // no output writer
    javaFileManager,
    null, // no Diagnostic Listener
    Arrays.asList("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6"),// source level Java 1.6
    null, // no APT processors
    sources
);
task.call();
```

And you can pass in a custom [`DiagnosticListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/DiagnosticListener.html) if you want to process output.

Answer (score 0):

You call `javac.exe` to compile Java.

You should be using Process to execute it:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html
http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part3/Chapter23/runExtProg.html